# Unchecked runtime.lastError: Cannot access contents of url. But I dont need to access content of that URL

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I am making a Chrome Extension. Below, I have pasted the manifest file for that.

**Manifest File**

```
{
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "name": "abc",
    "version": "0.1",
    "author": "def",
    "description": "",
    "permissions": [
        "tabs",
        "storage",
        "webNavigation",
        "*://www.youtube.com/*"
    ],
    "content_scripts": [{
        "matches": [
            "*://www.youtube.com/*"
        ],
        "js": [
            "content.js"
        ],
        "css": ["style.css"],
        "run_at": "document_end"
    }],
    "background": {
        "page": "background.html"
    },
    "browser_action": {
        "default_popup": "index.html",
        "default_title": "A tooltip popup description when you hover over the Chrome Extension icon."
    },
    "content_security_policy": "script-src 'self' https://www.gstatic.com/ https://*.firebaseio.com https://www.googleapis.com; object-src 'self'"
}
```

This extension is for youtube and thus I have requested permissions for that site only. I don't need access to other sites.

Sometimes I get the following errors:

> Unchecked runtime.lastError: Cannot access contents of url
> "https://www.skysports.com/football/news/11095/12055673/kalidou-koulibaly-gabriel-magalhaes-ben-white-who-are-the-most-in-demand-centre-backs-this-transfer-window".
> Extension manifest must request permission to access this host.

> Unchecked runtime.lastError: Cannot access contents of URL
> "https://material.io/resources/icons/?icon=linear_scale&style=outline".
> Extension manifest must request permission to access this host.

**Background.js**

```
// regex for youtube watch page
const regWatch = /^(http(s)?:\/\/)?((w){3}.)?youtu(be|.be)?(\.com)?\/watch\?+/gm;

var firebaseConfig = {
   // firebase project details 
};

// Initialize Firebase
firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
const database = firebase.firestore();


chrome.webNavigation.onHistoryStateUpdated.addListener(function(details) {
    console.log(details);
    // match if its youtube watch page
    if ((details.url).match(regWatch)) {
        chrome.tabs.executeScript(null, { file: "content.js" });

       
    } else {
        // any other website except youtube or
        // any other youtube page except the one with the watch in the URL
        console.log("NO need to run the script");
    }

});

chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(
    function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
        console.log(sender.tab ?
            "from a content script:" + sender.tab.url :
            "from the extension");
        if (request.data) {
           // call to firestore 
        }
        return true;
    }
);
```

Why am I getting those errors in the background script? If you need any other info feel free to ask.
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that executeScript without a tab id (`null` in your code) runs in the active tab (aka "currently focused" tab) but navigation can also occur in inactive tabs.

You need to use `details.tabId` in executeScript to run it in the tab where navigation occurred:

```js
chrome.tabs.executeScript(details.tabId, { file: "content.js" });
```

Further optimizations:

- It might be more efficient to use [simple messaging](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging) instead of re-injecting.
- The webNavigation event is triggered in iframes too so check details.frameId to skip them.
- Use [URL filters](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/webNavigation#event-onHistoryStateUpdated) to limit webNavigation events:

  ```js
  chrome.webNavigation.onHistoryStateUpdated.addListener(details => {
    if (!details.frameId) {
      chrome.tabs.executeScript(details.tabId, {file: 'content.js'});
    }
  }, {
    url: [
      {hostEquals: 'youtu.be'},
      {hostEquals: 'www.youtube.com', pathPrefix: '/watch'},
    ],
  });
  ```

Comment: Hey, thanks for answering. Could you please tell me how can I recreate these errors(to understand this better)? I mean what sequence of URLs that I visit would generate a similar message?

Comment: I don't quite understand what the inactive tab means. How could a navigated tab be inactive?

Comment: I think I understand it now. So suppose we have more than one tab opened in a window. and when the navigation event fires in one of these inactive tabs, the background page catches it. But because of null(the reason you have mentioned in the answer), I get this error for inactive pages.

Comment: Yes. I thought that was what my answer said but apparently it didn't so I edited it a bit.

Comment: Thanks. just 1 last question. Do I need to use {hostEquals: 'youtu.be'}. I only want to run the script in watch pages.

Comment: No, it's not needed, it's just an example of adding multiple urls.