# Is it possible to have two separate chrome.onHistoryStateUpdated Functions

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

This is currently the code that I have, which injects my custom stylesheet into a specific website when the history state gets updated (in my background.js):

```
chrome.webNavigation.onHistoryStateUpdated.addListener(function(details) {
  chrome.tabs.insertCSS(null,{file:"results.css"});

})
```

I want to add another listener similar to this in order to inject another one of my stylesheets into a different website when the history state is changed again. But I don't know if this is possible, and if it is, how to specifically call that second listener. Do I have to send a message from my content.js?

How can this be resolved?

Thanks!

-Colin

Comment: It'll be the same as yours but you should specify different URL filters ([example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63647993)) for each listener.

Comment: When I'm on the YouTube homepage and search something in the searchbox, it takes me directly to the results page, and inserts the css stylesheet properly. But when I click on the YT icon on the search page to go back to the homepage, it doesn't seem to register the change in URL. Is there any way to fix that?

Comment: That's because you also need to listen to onCommitted event. Actually, there's no need for webNavigation at all and you can switch to declaring [content_scripts](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts) with `css` for the entire youtube site.

Comment: But doesn't YouTube use history.pushState()? If I just declare my content scripts to be css, I can't just call it without listening for that updatedHistory event...

Comment: No. When you use CSS content script with a URL for the entire site it doesn't matter what the site does.